# Infinite loading image screen

Tags: java, android

My apologies if this question has already been asked, but I have an issue with my code seeming to get stuck at some point and just indefinitely trying to load an image on my tablet's (Nexus 7) cropping program. My program is supposed to allow a user to take a picture and then crop it. From there I will add more, but that part hasn't been added in yet. Perhaps my problem is a missing line in my manifest? Logcat pops up a line "V 03-06 13:43:52.296 7349 7349 StateManager destroy" after i go to crop the image. I am using the Eclipse IDE and used this site to help make this part of my program: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera/

Here's a snippet of what I think all is needed in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Here's the xml, there should be nothing wrong here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Scan" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/capture_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/capture" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/capture_btn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/pic_border"
    android:contentDescription="@string/picture" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Lastly, here's the .java file:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class Scan extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

//keep track of camera capture intent
final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
//captured picture uri
private Uri picUri;
//keep track of cropping intent
final int PIC_CROP = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //retrieve a reference to the UI button
    Button captureBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);
    //handle button clicks
    captureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.capture_btn) {
        try {
            //use standard intent to capture an image
            Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            //display an error message
            String errorMessage = "Whoops! Your device doesn't support image capturing!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
            //get the Uri for the captured image
            picUri = data.getData();
            //carry out the crop operation
            performCrop();
        }
        //user is returning from cropping the image
        else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){
            //get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            //get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
            //retrieve a reference to the ImageView
            ImageView picView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
            //display the returned cropped image
            picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
        }
    }
}

private void performCrop(){
    try {
        //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        //indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        //indicate output X and Y. Edit this line for width and height respectively
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
        //display an error message
        String errorMessage = "Whoops! Your device doesn't support the cropping!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Note, the problem was that picUri was returned as null.

Comment: Alternative solutions are greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Check what value of picUri you pass to the crop activity. If I pass null to a crop activity on my phone I got infinite loading too. If picUri is null, try to follow this http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html to take a photo. There they pass path of the output file to the capture activity.

Comment: Where is it you say they pass the output file to the capture activity? I can't understand or follow half the gibberish on the developer site.

Comment: `File f = createImageFile();
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));` But before following this, better check picUri value in `performCrop()`. If it's not null, there is no reason to change the way you take a photo.

Comment: That part's talking about naming the file after you've saved it permanently. I don't want to save the file permanently. I want to just get it temporarily before letting another program "read" any text on it. After that, the file should just be scrapped. Again though, I am just wanting to get the take picture and crop part working. Also, i will probably want to let the user decide the dimensions of the cropped image. I figure removing the parts for aspect and outputx/y will possibly do that.

Comment: checked and yes, the picUri is null.

Comment: When capture activity takes a photo, it saves it somewhere. In your code you try to receive this path in `onActivityResult()` in line `picUri = data.getData();`. Then you send this URI to the crop activity. In the article they create a path to the file, where taken image will be saved (you can specify the path and don't use the default). After that, you will have not null URI. You can delete this file after user cropped the image if you want.

Comment: My apologies if this is intuitive to you, but I'm not sure exactly how to do what they're saying to do. I feel this should be able to be done in just a couple lines of code and not involve permanent saving, just temporarily to the RAM. I just don't know how.

Comment: No, you should avoid keeping large images in RAM. Activities, that take photoes, won't return full image to you. You can retrieve thumbnail by `Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");` in `onActivityResult()`. But to get a full size image you must know, where the activity has saved it. And crop activity doesn't accept images from RAM. You must pass URI to it. Initialize picUri by some value (use approach from the article or another), and then add this uri to captureIntent: `captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);`.

Comment: This really doesn't help when I can't find any good methods for saving be it on the developer site or any where else. I'm not wanting to make an entire new method just to save a file, just a few lines inside my onActivityResult. I'm sure the answer is using File, but no one seems to have a half decent explanation anywhere I look and it's rather frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to my father, an electrical engineer who's programmed for years and seeing some of his programs; I made some changes to onActivityResult and added a save method that solved the problem.

New onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
            //save the pic
            try {
                File f = createImageFile();
                //get the Uri for the captured image
                picUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                //carry out the crop operation
                performCrop();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //user is returning from cropping the image
        else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){
            //get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            //get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
            //retrieve a reference to the ImageView
            ImageView picView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
            //display the returned cropped image
            picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
        }
    }
}
```

New save method:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String filename = new String("part");
    File image = File.createTempFile(filename, ".jpeg");
    return image;
}
```

Now the problem is in the next part, the crop method, which is a different question all together.